# I am trying to use GDAL convert format. Upon opening, I am receiving > AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'

Tags: qgis

QGIS Version: 3.28.7
I tried to upgrade it to 3.28.8 but the problem still persist.
Are there other options that I can try to solve this issue?

Error from Python Log>>
WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):

```
          File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\ProcessingPlugin.py", line 387, in executeAlgorithm

          dlg = alg.createCustomParametersWidget(parent)

          File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalAlgorithm.py", line 64, in createCustomParametersWidget

          return GdalAlgorithmDialog(self, parent=parent)

          File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalAlgorithmDialog.py", line 59, in __init__

          self.mainWidget().parametersHaveChanged()

          File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalAlgorithmDialog.py", line 147, in parametersHaveChanged

          commands = self.algorithm().getConsoleCommands(parameters, context, feedback, executing=False)

          File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\ogr2ogr.py", line 83, in getConsoleCommands

          ogrLayer, layerName = self.getOgrCompatibleSource(self.INPUT, parameters, context, feedback, executing)

          File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalAlgorithm.py", line 127, in getOgrCompatibleSource

          ogr_layer_name = GdalUtils.ogrLayerName(input_layer.dataProvider().dataSourceUri())

          File "C:\PROGRA~1/QGIS32~1.6/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\processing\algs\gdal\GdalUtils.py", line 419, in ogrLayerName

          return r.groups()[1]

         AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

Comment: Hi Suzuha, how is Mayuri doing these days? Your error message is detailed but there is no information on how you got to this error message, can you explain a little more about  how you're trying to convert the format please.

Comment: Hi @MichaelStimson . Mayuri is doing great. She's still looking for that silver Upa. Anyway, the error pops up when I open the convert format in GDAL toolbar. What I mean by opening is by double clicking the tool itself in the processing tools in QGIS. The plugin won't open and flags that error. Currently, I still don't have any ideas in solving this. The only thing I have tried is installing other version of qgis which is 3.28.8 but with no success. Looking forward for some light in this. El Psy Congroo.

Comment: Amane-san that does sound like a bug, do you perchance have a bad referenced (link lost) layer or no layers currently loaded. The source for the latest (online https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/master/python/plugins/processing/algs/gdal/GdalAlgorithm.py) reads like it's iterating through the layers that are loaded to populate a drop-down list, not finding any suitable layers and is returning None, that specific error in GdalUtils.py is referencing a table from a uri. I hope that's more helpful than a gel-nana.